# Using gateway with processing chain, Dispatcher has no subscribers error

Tags: spring-integration

I have below configuration, not sure what is wrong that i keep getting this error, appreciate your help, Thank you

```
    <int:chain input-channel="incoming">
        <int:splitter ref="split"/>
           <int:filter ref="filter" discard-channel="loggit" />
                <int:payload-type-router default-output-channel="loggit" >
                <int:mapping type="a.b.c" channel="channel1" />         
        </int:payload-type-router>      
   </int:chain>

   <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway 
                id="DB_POLLAR"
                data-source="dataSource"
                request-channel="channel1" 
                reply-channel="loggit"
                is-function="false"
                expect-single-result="false" 
                stored-procedure-name="PKG.proc_get">                   
                <int-jdbc:parameter name="rowid" expression="payload" />            
                <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="ataset" row-mapper="dataMapper"/>       
                <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
                    <bean class="com.a.b.c.DbCallAdvice" />
                </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>                
    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: I have another stored-proc-outbound-gateway that is wired via payload-type-router and for some reason that does not have this problem, quite puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>` is a `request/reply` component, so if your target procedure returns something it is wrapped to the `replyMessage` and Framework tries to send it to the `output(reply)-channel`.

Since you don't have it there, as well as don't have `replyChannel` header you end up with `Dispatcher has no subscribers error`.

If you aren't interested in the `reply` from that procedure, consider to use

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: I do have  reply-channel="loggit" there or  am i missing something else?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I see that. Do you have a component which is subscribed to that `loggit` channel ? Show please, StackTrace on the matter

Comment: Thanks Artem, loggit is logging channel adapter, just to print as of now. I was able to fix this but i don’t know why this happened in first place. I had a third <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway> defined in the file which i have not wired yet but i had put the same id for this one as the one generating error. changing its ID to something else fixed the error, if you could help to know how this works.

Comment: Agr... Yes, it is an issue. When several Spring beans have the same `id`, only the last one wins. So, that new unfinished component destroys your proper one. And that why your `channel1` raises that exception, because the ApplicationContext doesn't have a consumer for that.

Comment: Thanks again, btw my SPs are failing due to 'package name should be specified separately using '.withCatalogName' but i don't see a way to do that in configuration?